# Joins in Update statement in sqlite

Tags: join, update, sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE Table_1 (
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL ,
    EmailId VARCHAR
)

INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES (1,'raj@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES (3,'test@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES (4,'false5@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES (7,'false55@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES (8,'falsefalse@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES (9,'true1@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES (11,'true2@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES (12,'falsefalsefalse@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES (13,'ravi@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES (14,'rak@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES (15,'false@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES (16,'false66@gmail.com');


CREATE TABLE Table_2 (
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL ,
    EmailId VARCHAR
)

INSERT INTO Table_2 VALUES (1,'raj@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Table_2 VALUES (3,'test@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Table_2 VALUES (4,'false98@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Table_2 VALUES (7,'abc@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Table_2 VALUES (8,'ta@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Table_2 VALUES (9,'false1@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Table_2 VALUES (11,'false2@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Table_2 VALUES (12,'false@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Table_2 VALUES (13,NULL);
INSERT INTO Table_2 VALUES (14,NULL);
INSERT INTO Table_2 VALUES (15,'false@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO Table_2 VALUES (16,'false66@gmail.com');
```

I have two tables in sqlite like `Table_1` and `Table_2`

I need to update Entire `Table_1 EmailIds` Using `table_2 EmailIds` based on below conditions

condition-1)

- need to udpate when Table_1 EmailId<>table_2 EmailId (to all rows)

condition-2)

- If Table_2 EmailId is null don't need to update that null value in
  Table_1 partucular EmailId

as per the Above Tables with my requirement I want below output:--

1) I want to update  4,7,8,9,11,12 Id's

2) I don't want update 1,3,15,16 Id's(because same emailids in both tables)

3) I don't want update 13,14 Id's (because 13, 14  emailid are null values in Table_2)

For the above problem I wrote below query in MYSQL and SQL Server it's working fine, but in sqlite it's not working.

I found Joins will not work in Update statement in sqlite but I want an alternate solution. Can anybody help me please?

```
UPDATE Newcontacts n
  JOIN DummyContacts d  ON (n.Id=d.Id)
SET n.EmailId=d.EmailId
WHERE n.EmailId<>d.EmailId
  OR d.EmailId IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table_1
SET EmailId = (SELECT d.EmailId
                 FROM Table_2 d
                 WHERE Table_1.Id = d.Id
                 )
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT d.EmailId
                 FROM Table_2 d
                 WHERE Table_1.Id = d.Id
                   AND Table_1.EmailId <> d.EmailId
                   AND d.EmailId IS NOT NULL
                 );
```

Comment: Than Q very much, This Information very Useful for me.

Comment: You're wellcome. In any stack exchange forum, if your question is answered, mark the reply as correct :)

Comment: I tested this query , its working fine Than Q very much